# How do I retrieve the value as my enum type from a QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qmap

I have a `QMap` like this:

```
QVariantMap dictionary;
dictionary.insert("name", KeywordType::name);
```

but when I try to retrieve the value of `name` key as enum `KeywordType` type, which is `KeywordType::name` it return none (that's zero in the `KeywordType` enum):

```
  qDebug() << dictionary["name"].value<KeywordType>();
```

How do i fix this?

the enum type is registered to moc, it use:

```
Q_ENUM(KeywordType)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(keywords::KeywordType)
```

and

```
 qRegisterMetaType<KeywordType>("KeywordType");
```

to make know the typeded:

```
typedef keywords::KeywordType KeywordType;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply call `KeywordType(dictionary["name"].toInt());`?

Comment: I actually ended up doing this. I just wanted to know why it didn't work as enum, although

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find why this isn't working with my enum, so I eneded up doing this:

```
static_cast<KeywordType>(dictionary["name"].value<int>())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should get `name` value by `keywords::name` ? If `KeywordType` is an enum, it's not a namespace or class.

Comment: I ended up doing this: `static_cast<KeywordType>(dictionary["name"].toInt())`